# Ofstream working with directory and not working without it

Tags: c++, linux, file, clion, ofstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ofstream myfile;
    ofstream file2;
    myfile.open("/home/me/CLionProjects/Project2/xample.txt", ios::app); //this file doesn't exist
    file2.open("testingfile.txt", ios::app); // this file also doesn't exist
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
        cout<<"test"<<endl;
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout<<"error";
    if(file2.is_open())
    {
        file2<< "Writing this to a file";
        cout<<"test2";
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout<<"error";
return 0;
```

The result I get out of this code is: both myfile and file2 pass their if test and in the case of myfile new file xample.txt is saved in the directory I created. However, no new file "testingfile.txt" can be found on my computer(or I just can't find it). According to this source a new file should be created: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ 
What am I doing wrong?
EDIT: Operating system: Linux Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What operating system is this? Linux? Windows?

Comment: Linux ubuntu 18.04

Comment: how are you running this executable (from terminal? some other tool?)?

Comment: Fear the [Working Directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). It isn't always where you think it is.

Comment: I am using the latest Clion

Comment: Hop into a terminal. Run `g++ /path/to/main.cpp`, `./a.out` and then `ls` and you should see "testingfile.txt". My guess is that your IDE may be running your executable in some temporary folder that it then deletes after the run (which would delete the created file along with it).

Comment: @scohe001 You solved it! Thank you very much